# Set SwiftUI view to always stay one size

Tags: swift, xcode, responsive-design, swiftui

I have a view that I always want to remain the same size, I haven't made it responsive to different screen sizes as eventually it will convert to a PDF. How do I set a specific view to always remain a size, and when I show it in a sheet it will display in the same format, just scaled down?

This is the view I am trying to maintain the size and aspect ratio of:

```
ScrollView(.vertical){
    VStack(spacing: 0){   
        ForEach(processor.matchEvents){event in
            if(event.team.home == true){
                HomeArm(team: event.team, event: event) //Same as AwayArm, just changes text
            }
            else{
                AwayArm(team: event.team, event: event)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AwayArm: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var team: Team
    var event: MatchEvent
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let mins: String = String(event.time)
        
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 5, height: 200)
            HStack(spacing: 0){
                Spacer()
                Text("\(mins)'")
                    .font(.title)
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(team.teamTextColor)
                    .background(team.teamColor)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .modifier(RoundedEdge(width: 5, color: .black, cornerRadius: 40))
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 80, height: 5)
                VStack{
                    Text(event.event)
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("Event Details")
                        .font(.title2)
                    Text("\(event.player.shirtNumber) - \(event.player.playerName)")
                        .font(.title3)
                }.padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: 250, height: 150)
                .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(UIColor.lightGray), .gray]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                .cornerRadius(25)
                .modifier(RoundedEdge(width: 5, color: .black, cornerRadius: 30))
                
            }
            .padding(.top)
            .padding(.trailing, 35)
        }
    }
}
```

I want this to be displayed inside a sheet, but maintain the correct sizings and aspect ratio:

```
HStack{
    ScrollView(.vertical){
        MatchReportView()
    }
    Text("")           
}
```

Any help on keeping this the same size, all the time, would be appreciated

Comment: Persistent size can be achieved with only giving hardcoded frame, like you already used `.frame(width: 250, height: 150)`.